# Why is the South Pole Telescope located exactly at the South Pole?

Tags: optics, astronomy, earth, telescopes

I read that there is less atmospheric interference for [the telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Pole_Telescope) at the South Pole because the atmosphere is thin and there is less water vapor in the air. However this seems to be true for many locations on Antarctica? Are there any other reasons that this telescope is located at exactly the South Pole?

Comment: Because you need a supporting infrastructure, and there is already a scientific base at the south pole.

Comment: ps. I have used (remotely) a telescope at the south pole, so this is hardly a new idea. http://www.arcticphoto.co.uk/gallery2/antarctic/antpeople/antscience/ah0231-00.htm

Comment: It's also not quite exact. The ice moves by some amount (tens of meters per year, I think), and they're on the ice. I don't know if they can move the telescope, but I doubt that they do.

Comment: ...well, when they tried to locate the South Pole Telescope at the North pole, everyone got confused...

Comment: @RobJeffries wow....

Comment: In addition to legitimate scientific reasons, I have heard that there is also some level of latent cold-war competitive motivation for (primarily) the US to maintain a presence at the South Pole. Having scientific experiments there is a great excuse to fund a permanent facility as well as keep all the (military-run) logistics up and running.

Comment: The main reason is that the Southern Hemisphere is directed towards the galactic center. To observe the galactic center without the needs of correction to most of the earth movements the more or less terrestial fixed axis telescope is of high interest. Because of the logistic problems to reach the South Pole it in not the biggest interest. South Pole has cloudy weather rather often but not most.

Answer (score 22):

[Here are](https://pole.uchicago.edu/public/southpole.html) extra reasons to the dry air :

> During the winter, sunshine does not reach the South Pole; nighttime (or daytime in the summer) extends for months. The lack of daily sunsets and sunrises makes the atmosphere extremely stable. Conducting observations in the winter also removes another contaminant to millimeter/sub-millimeter observations - the sun. All these factors conspire to make the South Pole the perfect place for the South Pole Telescope.

The further north  these extra reasons for choosing the South Pole plateau become important, there will be increasing presence of the sun.

Comment: I think, on symmetry grounds, that the pole must be the place that maximises the continuously-dark (and similarly continuously-light in fact) intervals, so this smells like a good reason to me.

Comment: I disagree - the reasons are much more likely logistical, as described by dmckee. If the Amundsen-Scott station was at 85° S, you can bet that the 'scope would have gone there as well. The station was installed at the pole back in 1956, when none of this was a consideration; putting it at the pole was exclusively about bragging rights at the height of Cold-War competitiveness.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  They did have a choice between  one of the coastal stations, which would have been easier on the personnel, or the one on the pole, after all. These are the reasons they give for choosing  the pole. They would have been better supplied on the coast after all.

Comment: @annav Those are reasons to choose the central plateau. The question asks why the telescope is precisely at the pole itself.

Answer (score 20):

Just guessing here, but ...

Compare the regions with really good skies with the places that have infrastructure and people present. Most of the installations are coastal, right? Are those good places to put a telescope? And while the whole inland plateau has good skies, it has few occupied site, and only one operated by the US.

So what is the case for putting up some other (very expensive to build and maintain) installation, when you could just drop it by South Pole Station where they already maintain a year-round presence.

Comment: That then brings up the question of why the station was set up precisely at the pole, if it wasn't for astronomic reasons. But then again, if you just need to set up shop *somewhere* within a featureless plain of ice and any spot is as good as any other, you might as well go for the spot with the most cred, I guess.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the name "South Pole Region Telescope" would be *severely* unwerwhelming, indeed.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  The Amundsen-Scott Station was built back in the mid-50s as part of the International Geophysical Year (which had a particular focus on the Antarctic);  astronomy wasn't a big concern until the early '90s.  There does appear to have been a bit of East/West competition for the bragging rights as well; see [this article](http://www.southpolestation.com/trivia/igy/intro.html).

Comment: There's a number of [research bases in Antarctica](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Antarctica_Station_Map.png#/media/File:Antarctica_Station_Map.png), and more than just the Amundsen-Scott station are "inland". However, Amundsen-Scott is the only *US* station which is inland, which may be a consideration for a (US) NSF-funded telescope.

Answer (score 10):

If the telescope was situated directly on the southern axis of the earth's rotation, the telescope's declination axis would be at zenith. The base for  the axis would be level to the ground. In theory you could compensate for the earth's rotation with only one motion of the telescope. Also, its the only place on earth where the entire  southern celestial hemisphere is visible. Now, are these the reasons it is built there, probably not but they would be advantages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no scientific reason that the South Pole Telescope is located so close ([within a few 100 meters](http://georgebmoody.com/lego/sp/aerial-annotated.jpg), really) of the geographic south pole. It might as well be located a few hundred miles to either direction, no difference.

The reason is purely practical: On the South Pole, there exists very significant infrastructure in the form of the permanently staffed [Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amundsen%E2%80%93Scott_South_Pole_Station), including power generators, an airfield, telecommunication channels to get the data off to warmer offices ;) and of course permanent scientific and technical staff.

Alternative permanent research areas are mostly near the coast of Antarctica, and there indeed the seeing would be much worse. The two exceptions are the Russian Vostok station and the French/Italian Concordia station, but the South Pole Telescope is mostly US-funded. What is more, there are [dedicated pots of funding](https://www.nsf.gov/geo/opp/opportun.jsp) available for research in this location, as opposed to e.g. some high-altitude site in Chile.

Without a real scientific reason, it is clear that the question of why the Amundsen-Scott station is exactly at the pole is not a scientific one, but is geo-political in the context of the [emerging cold war in the 1950s](http://www.southpolestation.com/trivia/igy/intro.html).

That said, the extremely clean and dry air and the high altitude (almost 3km) at the south pole are crucial for a millimeter-telescope. But this location also means that the telescope has always the same sky above. That would be a show-stopper for a survey telescope, but is an advantage if you want to collect detailed ("deep") information about whatever area in front of you. Also it is nice when building a telescope since a simple azimuthal mount at the pole is in fact an equatorial mount there.

Finally, there is a long history of telescopes and instruments at the south pole for exactly these reasons. That in turn means that any new telescope, such as the South Pole Telescope, can now capitalize on a well-studied site, and can observe the same patches of sky to build on previous observations.